# Fitting a MLPRegressor model using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, mlp

I'm trying to use `GridSearchCV` with an MLPRegressor to fit a relationship between my input and output datasets. Does the `GridSearchCV.predict()` method use the best parameters learned during cross validation or do I need to manually create a new `MLPRegessor`?

Does this work?

```py
# Fitting a Regression model to the train data
MLP_gridCV = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=MLPRegressor(max_iter=10000, n_iter_no_change=30),
    param_grid=param_list,
    n_jobs=-1,
    cv=5,
    verbose=5,
)
MLP_gridCV.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Prediction
Y_prediction = MLP_gridCV.predict(X)
```

Or do I need to manually create a new model using the best parameters?

```py
best_params = MLP_gridCV.best_params_
best_mlp = MLPRegressor(
    hidden_layer_sizes=best_params["hidden_layer_sizes"],
    activation=best_params["activation"],
    solver=best_params["solver"],
    max_iter=10000,
    n_iter_no_change=30,
)
best_mlp.fit(X_train, Y_train)
best_mlp.predict(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `predict` method for the `GridSearchCV` object will use the best parameters found during the grid search. So your first block of code is correct. This applies to scikit-learn version 1.1.1 and goes back to at least 0.16.1 (the oldest version I spot checked)

This can be verified by checking the `GridSearchCV` documentation on the scikit-learn site.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV